# Data structure or pattern for efficient stack api, for multiple value types, consumers, and phases

Tags: c++

I have a custom graphics application for which I want to update the "attributes" of 0 or more "components" at runtime. The app runs at 60FPS. I want to be able to change these component attributes on a frame-by-frame basis. For every attribute, there is a default/fall-back value that will be used if the component doesn't use a custom value for that attribute.

Every frame, the app builds a list of components. There are 2 phases for building these components:

1. A definition phase.
2. At compile phase. This is a runtime version of 'compile'.

After the 2 build phases, there is a run phase, which does not make use of the attributes.

There may be lots of components built every frame, as in thousands. Different components use diffent
subsets of possible attributes. So, component A may use attributes (U, V, W), and component B
may use attributes (W, X), etc. The list of attributes which each component uses is fixed; neither the type
nor the amount changes at runtime.

Usually, I want to change the attribute values of a whole bunch of components at once, and only rarely change the
values of individual components. However, it is possible to change attribute values on a per-component basis.

My hope is to use some kind of stack api for this, as it could be use to modify the values of groups of components,
or just individual ones, depending on how attributes are pushed/popped from the attribute stack.
Unfortunately, I'm having no luck. The issue is that the attribute
values may be consume in 2 possible places: at "definition phase", at "compile phase", or both.
If I use a stack, and then push an attribute value at the definition phase, but then pop that value before the compile phase, then
that attribute is not available at the compile phase.

I'm stuck trying to accomplish the following:

1. Avoiding having each component instance have fields for each possible attribute value that it uses.
   This is because, most of the time, the component will either use the default attributes, or the same attributes
   values will be used for most components. It's a waste to have all components with fields that are unused most
   of the time.
2. Avoid copying the values of each attribute, for each component, every frame. Again, most components use the
   either the default value, of they use values shared by other attributes. Most of the copies would be a waste of processing.

**I'm looking for some data structure or pattern that would allow me to create this stack-based api while being (relatively)
efficient with the attribute value copies and memory size.**

This is the kind of API I'm trying to have:

```cpp
struct CompA {

    // Trying to avoid having this type of struct, for each instance.
    struct {
        int age;
        float weight;
        // ... many others
    } attributes;
};

int main() {
  Init();
  while(mainLoopExit == false) {
      DefineComponents();     // May define and consume per-component attributes.
      
      // Problem: any attributes 'popped' before here are not available to CompileComponents().
      // ... but, need them to be. 
      CompileComponents();    // May consume (not define) per-component attributes.
      RunComponents();        // Attributes baked into the components.
  }
  Shutdown();
  return 0;
}

void DefineComponents() {
    auto a = CompBuilder.Add<CompA>();
    auto b = CompBuilder.Add<CompB>();
    auto c = CompBuilder.Add<CompC>();
    
    // All 'a', 'b', and 'c' get these attribute values.
    AttributesPush(AttrType::Size, 42);
    AttributesPush(AttrType::Weight, 100);
    
    a.Build();
    
    // 'b' gets overridden 'Size' attribute value of 84.
    // It gets the 'Weight' of 100, which is already on the stack.
    AttributesPush(AttrType::Size, 84);    
    b.Build();      
    AttributesPop(); // Size    
    
    // Only 'c' gets the 'Age' attribute value.
    // It gets the 'Size' of 42.
    // It gets the 'Weight' of 100.    
    AttributesPush(AttrType::Age, 300);    
    c.Build();      
    AttributesPop(); // Age
    
    AttributesPop(); // Weight
    AttributesPop(); // Size
    
    PostDefineProcess(); // *Some* attributes are consumed here.
}

void CompileComponents() {
    foreach (auto& c: GetCompoents<CompA>()) {
        // Get either a custom attribute value for 'Size', if component has one, or get the default value.
        auto size = GetAttr(AttrType::Size, c); 
        DoSizeStuff(c, size);
    }
    
    foreach (auto& c: GetCompoents<CompB>()) {
        // ...
    }    
}
```

Comment: _"The app runs at 60FPS"_ can you be more specific about your application framework? If it's something like unity or sfml, that should be at least be mentioned in the tags, because it doesn't have any reasonable meaning for standard c++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's a custom graphics application.

Comment: I would make a `std::unordered_map` with keys as your components ids, and values as some index in some simple array/vector of attributes, at index 0 you'd have defaults, at index 1, a first group of specific attributes, at index 2, a second group of specific attributes. To assign components to a group you update the map with the index of a group (e.g. half of components would have group 1, other half group 2, a few would have 0 as default). Thus you can in O(1) change the whole group of attributes, and in O(1) change group index of a component. But constantly adding groups would be an issue

Comment: Though you could preallocate a big enough vector, so adding a group would also be O(1). Removing groups would also be an issue

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov: Based on your comment, I did something similar to what you described, and I was able to get the functionality working. If you set your comment as the answer, I'll click accept. Thank you; I had been stuck about how to solve this for a few days, and you laid out the answer nice and simply.

Comment: @Dess glad to hear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a `std::unordered_map` object, where keys would be your components ids, and values would be indices in another simple array/vector of attributes. E.g. at index 0 you'd have default values, at index 1 the first group of specific attributes, at index 2 the second group of specific attributes.

To assign components to a group you update the map with the index of a group (e.g. half of components would have group 1, other half group 2, a few would have 0 as default). Thus you can in O(1) change the whole group of attributes, and in O(1) change group index of a component.

However frequent adding removing of groups would be an issue.